Difference in behaviour of socketbinding betwen Linux and Windows in Python
I'm making a python lib that I want to be able to use in both Linux and Windows. But I'm experiencing issues when I'm trying to bind a socket to listen to a broadcast. It seems like on linux I need to bind it to "255.255.255.255" but on windows I need to bind it to each interface manually.
I made this short test script that works on Linux but not on windows:
import socket

test_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
test_socket.bind(("255.255.255.255", 51337))
while True:
    print(test_socket.recv(1024))

On Linux the messages appears as expected, but on windows I get
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context


If I instead change the broadcast address to the one currently used by the interface I want to listen to I get the messages as expected on windows, but on Linux I never receive anything. i.e:
import socket

test_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
test_socket.bind(("169.254.13.37", 51337))
while True:
    print(test_socket.recv(1024))

What am I doing wrong here, it feels like there should be a solution that doesn't involve coding different cases for windows and Linux?

"What am I doing wrong here" - have you tried binding to 0.0.0.0 yet? . "there should be a solution that doesn't involve coding different cases for windows and Linux" - They are different platforms with different behaviors, so sometimes you just have to write different code for each one.

Hello @RemyLebeau Thanks for the reply! If I bind to 0.0.0.0 it works both on Linux and Windows. If I understand it correctly this will bind it to all incomming messages on my chosen port?
Aboutt he different behaviours, As Python is a higher level language I thought that the socket lib would sort out differences in the underlying layers?

bind() doesn't bind to messages, it binds to devices. Binding to 0.0.0.0 will open your port on all local interfaces. Python may be higher level, but sockets are fairly low level without going into the OS layers.

Ah I see now two points where I missunderstanding things. Both on a bind level and on the abstraction of pythons sockets! Thanks a lot @RemyLebeau!
